# rospy Reaction to ROSCore Shutdown

Tags: ros, rospy, rosmaster, roscore, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running a node in python (or C++), is there a way to detect the loss of ROSCore or the ROSMaster?  I understand how to detect shutdown of the node itself, but need to be able to handle, in my own way, loss of ROSCore.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134791/rospy-reaction-to-roscore-shutdown/) by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 213 on 2014-03-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-03**:
Are you asking how to handle something like that or how to detect that this happened to be able to handle it?

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2014-03-03**:
Sorry, asking how to detect the loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case that it's lost there is obviously nothing left to ask if it's gone.
The simplest way might be to perform some [xmlrpc](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Master_API) call like getUri or similar and see if there is a reply.

The negative behavior (i.e. not reply) would be the same that a node sees that tries to interact with a non-existing master.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2014-03-08**:
Thanks.  That is what I expected, but I wasn't sure if there was some unknown function that I have not found.  I currently have a thread that does the "getUri" call and it works.